# Finding the max negative number, min postive number in C using ternary operato (no while loop, for loop )

Tags: c, conditional-operator

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);

    int max = (a < 0 ? a : 0);
    int mmin = (a > 0 ? a : 0);
    
    max = (b < 0 && b > max ? b : max);
    max = (c < 0 && c > max ? c : max);
    max = (d < 0 && d > max ? d : max);
    max = (e < 0 && e > max ? e : max);
    max = (f < 0 && f > max ? f : max);
    
    mmin = (b > 0 && b < mmin ? b :mmin);
    mmin = (c > 0 && c < mmin ? c :mmin);
    mmin = (d > 0 && d < mmin ? d :mmin);
    mmin = (e > 0 && e < mmin ? e :mmin);
    mmin = (f > 0 && f < mmin ? f :mmin);
    
    printf("The max negative number is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The min positive number is: %d\n", mmin);
}
```

So.. this is my code and when i try to run it, it has a problem with the output, example with " 1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 ", it gave me the min positive is 1 and max negative is 0 ( but not -2 ), anyone knows why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: What happens if you hard-code in the input?

Comment: I got `0` and `1` as the result when I compiled your code and gave it the inputs you provided. Please provide a copy of your terminal session where you tested this.

Comment: You can also debug with `printf`. For example, put `printf("max=%d min=%d\n", max, mmin);` after every line of code, and see what you get.

Comment: You should also check that your call to `scanf` actually returned `6`. Don't make assumptions about I/O.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not write a function which can handle finding this info in an array using loops? It seems like a strange restriction. Your string of codnitionals is basically just unrolling a loop.

Comment: @Minh Công Nguyễn "and min positive is 0 ( but not -2 ), anyone knows why " - Can you explain how can the minimum positive number be equal to -2 ?!

Answer (score 1):

Your code can, at best, give you one of the two things you're looking for. If the first number is positive, you will get the smallest positive value, but zero for the other. Vice versa if the first number is negative. The problem is setting `max`, `mmin`, or both to zero for the first number (`a`). Once either is zero, it will remain zero regardless of the subsequent values.

To fix this, your subsequent checks need to see if the current `max` or `mmin` is zero, and not use it for comparison in that case. If it is zero, then simply set it if the value is less than or greater than zero. If `max` or `mmin` is not zero, then you can do the compare to see if you should update it. (This is better than setting them initially to `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, because you would then not be able to tell if an input was one of those or not.) So:

```c
    int max = a < 0 ? a : 0;
    int min = a > 0 ? a : 0;
    max = b < 0 && (max == 0 || b > max) ? b : max;
    min = b > 0 && (min == 0 || b < min) ? b : min;
    max = c < 0 && (max == 0 || c > max) ? c : max;
    min = c > 0 && (min == 0 || c < min) ? c : min;
    ...
```

At the end, you can check if either of those is still zero, and if so, report that there were no such values (no negatives or no positives, or neither) in the input.

Comment: Personally, I would probably have defined an enum to indicate which values were found, then have a function which does this and takes two pointers to ints to store the min and max values in.